# Purpose of scoped_model/provide packages if built-in state management works

Tags: flutter

New to Flutter, so please forgive the question.

I'm playing around with the need to manage state (variables/objects) across the entire app using the Stateful widget - it's a bit cumbersome, but I get the method.

I see there are packages providing similar functionality (`scoped_model` and `provide`) - what do these bring to the mix and what problem do they solve?  Before embarking on one particular approach, I guess I'm asking what the seasoned Flutter devs are using and why?

Thanks

Comment: there are some articles on that, like: https://medium.com/flutter-community/easy-reactive-widgets-with-flutters-scoped-model-228272314dc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mainly about scalability & performance of your application. Using StatefulWidget is fine for small apps, but imagine if you had a widget tree of a depth of 30, and only 2 leaf widgets need to know about some `counter` value, and they're both at opposite ends of the widget tree. With `StatefulWidget` approach, you'd have to place the value at the top of the tree and pass it down the entire tree so the 2 widgets can get it. Then, after a while, you need another widget in a totally unrelated branch of the tree to get `counter` as well - now you need to modify that entire branch to also pass down the value. Then, later on, you decide to move one of the original leaves to a different place - again, you have to modify your entire codebase to accommodate that.

Using `InheritedWidget` makes that both `provider` and `scoped_model` use, you can instead just inject `counter` at the top of the tree and have the widgets that require it simply extract the value from their `context` using a `Consumer` or the `scoped_model` equivalent. This will also solve another issue: now that none of the intermediate widgets know about `counter`, they no longer need to rebuild when the value changes. You can now move your widgets around and add/remove dependencies on `counter` as you please and not mess with unrelated widgets as you do that.

You can even go a step further and use `bloc`s instead. I recall reading an article that compared all approaches and found that `bloc`s can further improve performance of your app by eliminating some builds, though it can be a little daunting to understand what's going on in the `bloc` pattern at first.

Comment: That's not true actually. There are ways of doing it without having this issue. Passing ValueListenable instead of the value directly for example

Comment: Agreed, you can definitely get StatefulWidgets to perform well. But, in the context of the question, as OP states, they're new to Flutter development, so I just assumed that they're passing down values as-is, in which case using StatefulWidgets could hinder the app's performance.

Answer (score 1):

Using StatefulWidget only is *not bad*.
You don't *have* to use provider/scoped_model.

StatefulWidgets are very powerful and scalable by default.

Their shortcomings are:

- they are very verbose
- it is difficult to reuse stateful logic between stateful widgets (although there are variants for it, like flutter_hooks)
- refactoring can be painful

These are things that InheritedWidgets solve, so provider/scoped_model too.

But as you can see, these are mostly quality of life issues. 
If you can support them, it's fine to use StatefulWidget only.